# React change initial state based on another field value

Tags: reactjs

How can I change the initial state value of a field based on the input value of another field?

Here's my code:

```
import React from "react";

export class someComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      grade: "",
      tuition: changeStateHere
    };
  }

  render() {
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={this.someFunction.bind(this)}>
        <select name="grade" onChange={this.onChange} value={this.state.grade}>
          <option value="">Class</option>
          <option value="Grade One">Grade One</option>
          <option value="Grade Two">Grade Two</option>
          <option value="Grade Three">Grade Three</option>
          <option value="Grade Four">Grade Four</option>
          <option value="Grade Five">Grade Five</option>
          <option value="Grade Six">Grade Six</option>
        </select>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="tuition"
          placeholder="Tuition"
          value={this.state.tuition}
          onChange={this.onChange}
        />
      </form>
    </div>;
  }
}
```

I want to set a dynamic initial state value for `tuition` based on input option on the `grade` select field.

For example, if a user selects `Grade One`, the `tuition` value should be 15000; if `Grade Two`, the value should be '20000'; etc.

Is there any workaround dynamically changing the initial state value?

Answer (score 0):

Everything inside of the `constructor` is run before `render`. You're not going to be able to set a different initial value to the state based on something inside the render method.

Also move away from binding functions in the render method. it would be better to use a class method `someFunction = () => {}` and then attach it inside the JSX as `onSubmit={this.someFunction}`

Each time the component re-renders another instance of `someFunction` is bound which will eventually lead to performance issues in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the grade selection and evaluate the `event.target.value` of the select element. Based on this you can use a switch to `this.setState` both Tuition and whether or not the input field is disabled. You should use `defaultValue` instead of value so that when the user picks and option it sets the input to `this.state.tuition`

```
import React from "react";

export class someComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      grade: "",
      gradeSelected: false,
      tuition: 0,
    };
  }

  handleGradeSelect = event => {
    let newState = Object.assign({}, this.state) // duplicate state so you can mutate this copy
    switch(event.target.value){ // evaluate the value of the select option
      case 'Grade One':
        newState.tuition = 15000
        case 'Grade Two':
        newState.tuition = 20000
        // You get the picture
       default:
        newState.tuition = 0 // needs to have a default if no option
    }
    newState.gradeSelected = true
    this.setState(newState)
  }

  render() {
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={this.someFunction.bind(this)}>
        <select name="grade" onChange={event => this.handleChange(event)}>
          <option disabled>Class</option>
          <option value="Grade One">Grade One</option>
          <option value="Grade Two">Grade Two</option>
          <option value="Grade Three">Grade Three</option>
          <option value="Grade Four">Grade Four</option>
          <option value="Grade Five">Grade Five</option>
          <option value="Grade Six">Grade Six</option>
        </select>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="tuition"
          placeholder="Tuition"
          value={this.state.tuition}
          onChange={this.onChange}
          disabled={!this.state.gradeSelected}
        />
      </form>
    </div>;
  }
}
```